# iOS8: Spotlight keyboard missing

Tags: spotlight, ios

When I open Spotlight on iOS8 on my iPhone 6 Plus I get the Spotlight Search but occasionally I have no keyboard.

Any suggestions how I get the keyboard back other than rebooting which takes a significant chunk of time?

Comment: I get the same from time to time. Annoying if you use Spotlight to launch apps a lot. Seems to be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by third party keyboard, but inconsistently as you say. Also happens in other apple apps like messages and email. For spotlight key board you'll need to go to another app that uses a keyboard and then switch to the standard apple keyboard. Then go back to spotlight and should be fine. For messahes and email apps you have to kill the app and restart it (double click the home button, then swipe the offending app upwards). Really annoying though and apple need to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix is to launch notes and compose a bogus note with the Apple keyboard, then change keyboard back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no aetting to enable/disable the keyboard so i think the best way to solve your problem is by preforming a hard reset by holding the power and home button untill the apple logo appears.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I just want to clarify that this bug is still present in IOS 8.4 with all the different custom keyboards.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment.